# How to perform insert array similar to numpy.put but change the size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am hoping to to write a setitem function which I can replace a subset of a numpy array with another array that may or may not be the same length .shape[0] (but always the same column size .shape[1]).

For example, using `numpy.put()` will be bound to the shape of the array.

```
a = np.arange(10)
np.put(a, [2,3], [80, 80, 80, 80])
array([ 0,  1, 80, 80,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])
```

But I am hoping to extend `a` to a new shape:

```
array([ 0,  1, 80, 80, 80, 80,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])
```

At the moment what I did is to create a new array based on what the new shape will be. Then assign each part accordingly:

```
a = np.ones((10, 2)) * 2
b = np.ones((4, 2)) * 80

def insert(a, pos, b):
    start = pos[0]; end = start + b.shape[0]
    c = np.ndarray((b.shape[0] - len(pos) + a.shape[0], a.shape[1]))
    c[:start] = a[:start]  # The first part is still a
    c[start:end] = b       # The middle part being replace by b
    c[end:] = a[pos[-1] + 1:]  # The remaining is also a . 
    return c

a = insert(a, [2, 3], b) # Insert a longer to array to the position 
array([[ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [80., 80.],
       [80., 80.],
       [80., 80.],
       [80., 80.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.]])

d = insert(a, [2,3,4,5,6], b)  # Insert a shorter array to the position
array([[ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [80., 80.],
       [80., 80.],
       [80., 80.],
       [80., 80.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.]])
```

It seems to work but also seems very inefficient as I am dealing with audio data so the size is pretty large.

Please advice if there is a more pythonic or numpy way to effectively insert a mismatch size of array into another array.

Comment: The behavior that you want is builtin for Python lists, but requires your kind of copy for `ndarray`.  Of course even lists do a lot of copying and moving under the covers.  You can't maintain a contiguous databuffer any other way.

Comment: So it seems there is no effective way anyway since the main overhead is in the memory allocation?

Comment: For your small example, `np.concatenate([a[:2,:], b, a[4:,:]], axis=0)` is slightly faster.